# Semi-continuity of intersection numbers

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, intersection-theory

I always trusted the following quite vague statement:

If you have a family of effective divisors $D_1(t),\dots , D_k(t)$ on a $k$-dimensional projective variety $X_t$, where $t$ is a paramater say varying in disc, then the intersection number $D_1(t)\cdots D_k(t)$ can only increase under specialisation of $t$.

Without any flatness assumption on $D_i(t)$ and $X_t$ this is false, as shown in the post
[Semicontinuity of degree of fibers for a proper map](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/176064/semicontinuity-of-degree-of-fibers-for-a-proper-map)

I guess, under an appropiate fltaness assumption, my belief follows from the standard semi-continuity theorem (Hartshorne III.11). However, I was not able to find any precise statement/reference.

I would like to have a precise statment about the semi-continuity of intersection numbers, with possibly a reference in the literature.

This should also fit with the question
[More upper/lower semi-continuous functions in (algebraic) geometry?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/42796/more-upper-lower-semi-continuous-functions-in-algebraic-geometry)

Comment: In $\mathbb{P}^1$ with homogeneous coordinates $[x,y]$, consider the closed subscheme in $\mathbb{P}^1\times \Delta$ with defining ideal $\langle x^2,tx\rangle$.  That is a closed subscheme that is not flat over $\Delta$.  However, its intersection with the fiber over every $a\in \Delta$ is a divisor in $\mathbb{P}^1$.  Except if $a=0$, that divisor has degree $1$.  For $a=0$, the divisor has degree $2$.  Most algebraic geometers would not consider the closed subscheme to be a "family of divisors", i.e., they would impose a flatness hypothesis (or some hypothesis equivalent to flatness).

Comment: this example does not contradict a semi-continuity statement about intersection numbers. Anyway, I will make more precise my question

Comment: It contradicts lower semi-continuity.

Comment: Anyway, if you want a contradiction to upper semi-continuity, consider the same type of example with $D_1(t) = D_2(t) = D(t)$ a family of divisors on a surface with negative self-intersection.

Comment: ... or just use my example, but with -1 coefficients on the divisors.

Comment: @JasonStarr Is it even simpler if we just take a single (closed) point in $P^1\times\Delta$?

Comment: @FanZheng.  Yes, that is even simpler.

Comment: I am happy with the fact that the intersection number can go up, a bit less happy with the fact that it can go down. (I have in mind the example of the dimension of the fibre of a morphism: the dimension can only go up under specialisation, not down). For instance, take the divisor to be effective. I do not quite understand the example with divisor with negative self-intersection.

Comment: I just found another relevant post! I'll updated my question